# php/mysqli update database table - best way

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a DB-Table "shop_article" that has about nearly 100000 records.
Now every 10 Minutes a file has to be processed that contains changes of the article. Mostly the file has 5000 - 30000 records.

At the moment I go like this:

- Copy shop_article in shop_article_work per (insert into select * from).
- read csv-File per fgetcsv
- check if the records exists in shop_article_work
- update or insert in _shop_article_work
- truncate shop_article and copy shop_article_work to shop_article

My problem is now in the last step. If I truncate the shop_article all request from users get an empty result at this time.

I tried also a version with updating the shop_Article permanent without _work-Table but the performance was very bad because the user and the update-script disturb each other.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A few options:
- consider working inside a transaction
- or use "rename table" at the end of your process instead of truncate+copy
- or use a "last_update" timestamp mechanism to identify the changes and work effectively on them instead of full replacement of the table.

Comment: Put a timestamp column in `shop_article`, and remember the time when you started step 1. In the last step, just delete all the records whose timestamp is before the remembered time.